# Как сохранить информацию о положении блоков без использования AJAX?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. Есть [плагин](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), который позволяет
перемещать блоки местами. Как можно сохранить
информацию о положении блоков в базе без AJAX?
По нажатии на кнопку сохранить.

**UPD:** интересует передача методом POST по нашатии на кнопку сохранить.
Без Аякса.

Comment: как ни крути, а нужно как-то послать данные на сервер, чтобы сохранить в базе данных. Можно обычным POST/GET запросом с помощью формы, но тогда будет перезагрузка страницы, я полагаю. А чем AJAX не угодил?

Comment: В таком вопросе без AJAX лучше не надо, лучше поднапрячься  и сделать с AJAX. И потом, на сегодняшний день, мало кто знает что за AJAX стоит то. Есть масса библиотек, плагинов и пр., которые предлагают готовые решения для этого. Например: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Запрос в гугле: "как использовать ajax jquery" выдает массу сайтов на русском языке по данной теме. Успехов!

Comment: И всё таки, можно без аякса методом POST передать данные?

Comment: Ну конечно можно! При передвижении блоков создавать динамическую форму с нужными значениями в инпутах при каждом передвижении блоков и посылать эту форму на сервер, при нажатии одной кнопки.

Comment: И все-таки... Какая ваша причина отказа от ajax-а? 

1. "Пробовал, но ничего не получается."
2. "Даже не стал пробовать, т.к. для меня это кажется дремучим лесом"

Ведь вы всё равно используете jQuery. Так в чем же проблема?

Comment: Что-то не совсем понял. Что такое динамическая форма?

Comment: Мне нужен именно вариант, чтобы сохранение шло по нажатии кнопки СОХРАНИТЬ. У меня там около 30 блоков, которые местами меняться будут. И не хочется, чтобы после каждого сохранения выскакивало сообщение СОХРАНЕНО. Сообщение конечно можно и не выводить, но всё таки аякс не хочется.

Comment: А jQuery использую, потомучто без него не знаю, как сделать такой эффект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как мне видится решение этой задачи без `AJAX`:

1. Создаем форму со скрытыми инпутами, в которых уже есть информация о первоначальном положении блоков, типа `<input type="hidden" name="block_{block_id}" value="{block_position_id}" />`
2. При каждом передвижении блока/блоков, срабатывает же какая-то там функция? Стало быть в этой самой функции обновляем значения этих инпутов на новые в соответствии с номером блока.
3. При нажатии на кнопку сохранить посылаем все это добро на сервер, где производим нужную обработку данных для сохранения в базе данных.

Comment: Вопрос в том, какая там функция срабатывает? И как обновить значение скрытого поля?

Comment: Полагаю, что этот event Вас интересует: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change

Comment: А есть ли эта информация на русском?

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/JQuery_UI

Comment: Ссылка не работает.

Comment: Уже работает

Comment: Можно через iframe :)

Comment: и еще хранить можно в куках.